# How can we sort dictionaries in an array by a specific key in pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, pharo-5

I have an array containing several dictionaries. How can I sorted them using a key that each dictionary have like age?

```html
an Array((a Dictionary('age'->'20' 'ID'->1254))(a Dictionary('age'->'35' 'ID'->1350))(a Dictionary('age'->'42' 'ID'->1425)))
```

Comment: Just use a sort block. For example, to sort in ascending order of the valu e for `'age'`: `anArrayOfDictionarys sort: [ :a :b | (a at: 'age') < (b at: 'age') ].` The Pharo/Smalltalk documentation is your friend and first line of defense in knowing these things. :)

Comment: @lurker can you link me to docs describing sort:/sorted:? because I don't recall it ever seeing in any Pharo book.

Comment: @Peter well.... I apologize, I guess I spoke too soon. I knew Pharo ordered collections accepted the `sort:` message, but evidently the docs are not up to date.

Comment: ludo, It seems @Peter answered your question spot on. Is there anything missing that prevents you from accepting his answer?

Comment: yes indeed lurker It seems like what I need @Peter. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can sort by providing a comparator block; the block takes two arguments (two elements from the array) and is expected to return boolean.

```
data := { 
    { 'age' -> '20'. 'ID' -> 1254 } asDictionary.
    { 'age' -> '35'. 'ID' -> 1350 } asDictionary.
    { 'age' -> '42'. 'ID' -> 1425 } asDictionary
}.
sorted := data sorted: [ :a :b | (a at: 'age') > (b at: 'age') ].
```

- `sorted:` will return a sorted collection without changing the receiver
- `sort:` will perform the sorting in-place and return itself

You can also use `asSortedCollection:` which will create a new collection that always upholds the sorting invariant.

```
sc := data asSortedCollection: [ :a :b | (a at: 'age') > (b at: 'age') ].

"automatically inserted between age 42 and 35"
sc add: {'age' -> '39'. 'ID' -> 1500} asDictionary.
sc "a SortedCollection(a Dictionary('ID'->1425 'age'->'42' ) a Dictionary('ID'->1500 'age'->'39' ) a Dictionary('ID'->1350 'age'->'35' ) a Dictionary('ID'->1254 'age'->'20' ))"
```